# The type or namespace for SQLiteConnection could not be found

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

I am trying to build a Xamarin form and came across this error while coding

"the type or namespace for SQLiteConnection could not be found".

I installed sqllite-new-pcl for this project and can see it under references tab.

I have added the following in the code but it is throwing error:
using SQLite;

Comment: @Jason the above mentioned package is not being mainted anymore!!

Comment: Try to uninstall and reinstall it.